# Shell to pull data from multiple servers using scp

Tags: shell-script, shell, scp

I am new to shell world, writing a simple script to pull files from more that 300 servers. Wanted to know if I am writing like below then it will login to all 300 servers in one go and pull files or it will go one by one. Also I have passwordless login for one user that user I can mention in $username or I need to create other script for that.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /backup
for server in $(cat server.txt)
do
scp -r  $username@$server:/tmp/backup/*.txt* .
done
```

Comment: Please focus on a single, precise question.

Answer (score 0):

Written like this, it will go one by one.

Have a look at `parallel` (you may need to install a software package) to execute it in parallel. Also, don't do all 300 at once, limit the number of concurrent executions (or it will be slower overall).

You can have passwordless login; you'll need to create an ssh keypair, put the private key into the machine from which you do `scp`, and put the public key into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on all the 300 machines you copy from. If the keys are in the right places, you don't need to change your script.

Comment: Thanks dirkt for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Like dirkt said, this will execute each command sequentially -- i.e. it won't start the next copy until the first one is done.

If you want to script to run in a reasonable amount of time you can append the `&` character to the end of a line or code block (placed in braces) to run the command in the background and immediately start the next one like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for server in $(cat server.txt); do
    scp -r  $username@$server:/tmp/backup/*.txt* /backup/ &
done
```

Comment: Thanks SapphireYETi - will ran above script on few servers.

Comment: And this will run 300 copies in parallel, which will probably saturate the network, and very likely make it slower overall. Which is why I meantioned `parallel` in the first place.